# Do referees and search committee generally value a fully self-written proof over a short proof citing many other theorems?

Tags: theory, research-process

Suppose that a researcher is trying to solve an important hypothesis within an economic model. He has two options to put his efforts:

1. He can start with the assumptions that he is most comfortable with, trying to prove the hypothesis all by himself, and finally come-up with a twenty pages proof after three months.
2. He can start surveying literature in Math and mathematically social science, in which he will be able to find similar mathematically structures (but different economic meanings). After two months, he will find some theorems that can be applied into the original hypothesis, and therefore write down a one-page proof for the hypothesis, with some tweaks of the assumptions.

In general, is a lengthy yet self-written mathematical proof an important contribution in economic theory research and valued by the referees and the search committee?

Comment: I think this is impossible to answer definitively. "It depends" is about all you can say. There is no "bright line" division between these two alternatives. Moreover it depends on the individual reader and their familiarity with the specific content.  Even "lengthly" is relative, though twenty pages is a lot to slog through if much of it is already known.

Comment: They probably value good logical reasoning and actual contributions to the field that are both original and useful. Comparisons to existing theories and "mathematical structures" is always necessary: good research explains why it is useful, how it relates to what has been done before, how the new method is different, and why it is better (or interesting for other reasons).

Comment: _finally come-up with a twenty pages proof after three months_ vs. _After two months, he will find some theorems that can be applied into the original hypothesis, and therefore write down a one-page proof for the hypothesis_: Neither route is guaranteed to work. A hybrid is perhaps better, especially when the researcher knows the literature well and knows which results may help.

Comment: @user2768 I do agree with you. Of course everything has its risks. The two options are just two idealized examples to confine the scope of this question, making this question clearly defined and thus not opinion-based.

Comment: I think the main issue here is whether the long, self-written proof is largely a re-discovery of the results that were already in the literature or whether it is a new approach to the problem.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Of course it is not a rediscovery as the two proofs are based on different (albeit slightly) assumptions.

Comment: *it is not a rediscovery as the two proofs are based on different* --- I think what @Andreas Blass means by results includes method(s) of proof. In mathematics it is common to have existence proofs that either don't allow one to obtain an explicit construction (and this can have many different meanings) or only with difficulty allow one to obtain an explicit construction (and even then, the explicit construction might be especially unnatural in certain respects). Also, some proofs might allow a lot of adaptability in other ways while other proofs are essentially one-trick ponies.